# Как ограничить движение SeekBar?

Tags: android

Задался вопросом как реализовать несколько сикбаров, но так чтобы они могли двигаться на увеличение пока есть очки, общие для всех сикбаров.

Пример. У меня есть переменная `points: Int = 10` c общими очками для сикбаров. И пусть будет 2 сикбара с максимальным значение равным `points`, то есть 10. Движение ползунка расходует общие очки и когда очки заканчиваются, ползунок должен блокироваться для дальнейшего движения, но не для обратного движения. Например я выставил на одном сикбаре положение 7, значит для другого остается только 3. И хотелось бы чтобы доступная для движения часть сикбара ограничивалась диапозоном 0-3. Чем дальше двигается один сикбар, тем меньше активная область у другого.

Это можно сделать родными средствами? В гугле нашел только упоминания про `seekbar.max = N`, но это меняет всю шкалу а вместе с ней и положение ползунка в конец сикбара

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, что это можно реализовать, пользуясь "родными средствами", примерно так:

```
SeekBar sb1, sb2;
OnSeekBarChangeListener OSBCL;
int progress1, progress2, dif;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 //Остальной код помещаете согласно Вашему плану

sb1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sb1);
sb2 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sb2);

//R.id.sb1 и R.id.sb2 - id элементов в макете, их можно изменить

sb1.setMax(10);
sb2.setMax(10);

//Здесь и далее 10 - это переменная

OSBCL = new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

  @Override
  public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar sb){
    switch(sb.getId()){
      case R.id.sb1:
        progress1 = sb1.getProgress();
      break;
      case R.id.sb2:
        progress2 = sb2.getProgress();
      break;
    };
  };

//Замечаем прогресс на начало изменения и записываем в переменные progress1 и progress2

  @Override
  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar sb, int progress, boolean fromUser){
    switch(sb.getId()){
      case R.id.sb1:
        int ch_progress1 = sb1.getProgress();
        int setprogress2 = 10 - ch_progress1;
        dif = progress1 - ch_progress1;
        if (dif < 0){
          if (progress2 > setprogress2){
            sb2.setProgress(setprogress2);
          };
        };
        progress1 = sb1.getProgress();
      break;
      case R.id.sb2:
        int ch_progress2 = sb2.getProgress();
        int setprogress1 = 10 - ch_progress2;;
        dif = progress2 - ch_progress2;
        if (dif < 0){
          if (progress1 > setprogress1){
            sb1.setProgress(setprogress1);
          };
        };
        progress2 = sb2.getProgress();
      break;
    };
  };

//ch_progress1 и ch_progress2 - текущие положентя SeekBar, узнаём разницу между текущим и предыдущим и задаём новый прогресс. В конце обновляем предыдущее положение

  @Override
  public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar sb){
    switch(sb.getId()){
      case R.id.sb1:
        progress1 = sb1.getProgress();
      break;
      case R.id.sb2:
        progress2 = sb2.getProgress();
      break;
    };
  };
};

sb1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OSBCL);
sb2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OSBCL);

//Назначаем слушатель

}
```

Мой код не претендует на звание лучшего, поэтому возможны некоторые оплошности в записи, но работает он как надо.

Comment: Хм.. интересно. В конце недели вернусь домой с моря, попробую, отпишусь

Comment: @GregoryBass, надеюсь, Вы вернулись

Comment: да, жив-здоров, спасибо))